# Include jars files from the sub folders in gradle

Tags: gradle

We maintain different folders to keep all the jars.

Ex:

```
Repo
\-- lib
    \-- test
        \-- junit.jar
    \-- hibernate
        \-- hibernate.jar
```

I used the bellow code.

```
repositories {
    flatDir {dirs "../Repo/lib/*"}      
}
```

If I put all the jars in lib it works fine. But If I put it in different folders it give the compilation error.

I tried with this

```
repositories {
        flatDir {dirs "../Repo/lib/**"}     
    }
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When declaring a `flatDir` repository, you need to pass a (relative or absolute) *directory* path. You can't use wildcards, but may pass multiple directory paths. For example:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs "../Repo/lib/lib1", "../Repo/lib/lib2"
    }
}
```

For further details, see the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).